# Xcode 5.1: any way to suppress Revert/"Keep Xcode Version" dialog

Tags: xcode, xcode5.1

As of Xcode 5.1, when I change the project out from under Xcode (in my case, most commonly, by checking out another git commit), it throws up an annoying dialog, even when not active:

[image]

Worse, I'm using Spaces (or Mission Control... whatever the hell it's called now), and the dialog gets separated from Xcode and lost, and yet it's modal and keeps Xcode from accepting input. Sometimes I find it, or it pops up in the Xcode space. Sometimes this requires force-quit on Xcode to get control back.

Short of quitting Xcode every time I change commits, is there any way to end this madness?

Answer (score 9):

I chose revert to disk because the "disk" is the new code which I just pulled down from my repo. "keep xcode" is the code that was sitting there before I chose to change branches or pull rebase.

Answer (score 2):

Just close the project that you're going to make the change on before you make the change. I always close projects before I check out a different commit or branch, and never have this issue. It's safer to do it that way, too.

I don't think there's any way to just suppress it altogether, and if you did, you would have to choose a default behavior for it, which wouldn't necessarily always bet he same. So it would be a bad idea for Apple to give you an option of not showing it.

Comment: I *always* want to revert. I don't judge, but that's the way I roll. In 2014, forcing us to quit to accomplish this is just bad design, IMO.

Comment: Agreed. Not one single time I needed the "Keep Xcode Version".